# To form a drop down on side menu of ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to this ionic framework so my task is to make nested drop down on 
 side menu which i have made and its working fine. When i click on any item like "act&ser" it show its list and then again i click on "Courses" it again show another list inside it.By clicking it again the method toggle123('{{ChildNames.id}}')    hide its list.
         But the  problem is when i again click on "act&ser" which run toggle('{{x.id}}') method  to hide my whole dropdown list but its not hiding. I want my dropdown list to get hide on clicking "act&ser" So can you please help me.

Here my image is
[Link of Image what i have made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpNAn.png)

In menu.html file

```
  <ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="x in names" ng-click = "toggle('{{x.id}}')">
   {{ x.name }}

<ion-list ng-show="myVar_{{x.id}}"> 

  <ion-item ng-repeat="ChildNames in x.children" ng-click = "toggle123('{{ChildNames.id}}')">
         {{ChildNames.name}}
      <ion-list ng-show="myVar1_{{ChildNames.id}}" >
        <ion-item ng-repeat="NestedChildNames in ChildNames.children1"  >
          {{NestedChildNames.name}}
        </ion-item>
     </ion-list>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-item>
```

In controller file the function is

```
 $scope.toggle123 = function(parentid1) {
    $scope['myVar1_'+parentid1]  = !$scope['myVar1_'+parentid1];
    console.log("Hiiiiiiiiiiiiii I am here");

};

$scope.toggle = function(parentid) {
    //$scope['myVar_'+parentid]  = !$scope['myVar_'+parentid];
    if(flag)
     {
        $scope['myVar_'+parentid] = 'true';  
        flag = false;
        //console.log($scope['myVar_'+parentid]);
     }
     else
     {
        $scope['myVar_'+parentid] = 'false';
        //console.log($scope['myVar_'+parentid]);
        flag = true;
     }        
};
```

My json format is

```
[  
   {  
      "children":[  
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Arts & Lifestyle",
                  "id":4
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fitness Classes",
                  "id":12
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Language Classes",
                  "id":16
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Performing Arts",
                  "id":38
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Sports Classes",
                  "id":70
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Educational Classes",
                  "id":82
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Kids Courses",
                  "id":91
               }
            ],
            "name":"Courses",
            "id":3
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Aircon Services",
                  "id":93
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cleaning Services",
                  "id":94
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Corporate Sales",
                  "id":95
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Courts Connect",
                  "id":96
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Courts Flexi Plans",
                  "id":97
               }
            ],
            "name":"Courts Services",
            "id":92
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Restaurant",
                  "id":99
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Café",
                  "id":100
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fast Food",
                  "id":101
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Buffet",
                  "id":102
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Pubs & Bars",
                  "id":103
               }
            ],
            "name":"Dining Vouchers",
            "id":98
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Extended Warranties",
            "id":104
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Adventure Parks",
                  "id":106
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Gaming",
                  "id":107
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Movies",
                  "id":108
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Sports Activities",
                  "id":109
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Theatres",
                  "id":128
               }
            ],
            "name":"Leisure & Entertainment",
            "id":105
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Africa",
                  "id":133
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Asia",
                  "id":134
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Australia",
                  "id":135
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Europe",
                  "id":136
               },
               {  
                  "name":"North America",
                  "id":137
               },
               {  
                  "name":"South America",
                  "id":138
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Southeast Asia",
                  "id":139
               }
            ],
            "name":"Travel",
            "id":132
         }
      ],
      "name":"act & ser",
      "id":2
   },
   {  
      "children":[  
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Services",
            "id":141
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Anniversary",
                  "id":143
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Birthday",
                  "id":148
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Condolences",
                  "id":153
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Farewell",
                  "id":156
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Get Well",
                  "id":161
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Graduation",
                  "id":166
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Grand Opening",
                  "id":169
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Housewarming",
                  "id":174
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Love & Romance",
                  "id":179
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Mother's Day Flowers",
                  "id":186
               },
               {  
                  "name":"New Borns",
                  "id":190
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Thank You",
                  "id":195
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Wedding",
                  "id":200
               }
            ],
            "name":"Flowers",
            "id":142
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Cakes",
                  "id":206
               },
               {  
                  "name":"For Her",
                  "id":207
               },
               {  
                  "name":"For him",
                  "id":208
               },
               {  
                  "name":"For Newborns and Mums",
                  "id":209
               }
            ],
            "name":"Gift",
            "id":205
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Gift Vouchers",
            "id":210
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Chocolate Baskets",
                  "id":212
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fruit Baskets",
                  "id":213
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Gourmet Hampers",
                  "id":214
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Organic Hampers",
                  "id":215
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Wellness Hampers",
                  "id":216
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Wine Hampers",
                  "id":217
               }
            ],
            "name":"Hampers",
            "id":211
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Beer",
                  "id":219
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Liquor",
                  "id":232
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Wine",
                  "id":238
               }
            ],
            "name":"Wine, Beers & Spirits",
            "id":218
         }
      ],
      "name":"Alcohol, Flowers & Gifts",
      "id":140
   },
   {  
      "children":[  
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Services",
            "id":248
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Baby Girl",
                  "id":250
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Baby Boy",
                  "id":266
               }
            ],
            "name":"Baby",
            "id":249
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Tops & Tees",
                  "id":280
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Bottom",
                  "id":283
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Clothing Sets",
                  "id":287
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shoes",
                  "id":288
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Sleepwear",
                  "id":289
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Socks",
                  "id":290
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Swimwear",
                  "id":294
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Undergarments",
                  "id":299
               }
            ],
            "name":"Boy",
            "id":279
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Bottom",
                  "id":306
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Clothing Sets",
                  "id":314
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shoes",
                  "id":315
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Sleepwear",
                  "id":316
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Socks & Hosiery",
                  "id":317
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Swimwear",
                  "id":322
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Tops & Tees",
                  "id":328
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Undergarments",
                  "id":333
               }
            ],
            "name":"Girl",
            "id":305
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Accessories",
                  "id":339
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Bottom",
                  "id":373
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Clothing Sets",
                  "id":380
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Hoodies & Sweatshirts",
                  "id":381
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Jacket & Coats",
                  "id":382
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Men Underwear",
                  "id":383
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Outerwear",
                  "id":389
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shirts",
                  "id":390
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Socks",
                  "id":395
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Swimwear",
                  "id":403
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Weatherwear & Accessories",
                  "id":409
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shoes",
                  "id":426
               }
            ],
            "name":"Men",
            "id":338
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Accessories",
                  "id":440
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Bottom",
                  "id":500
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Clothing Sets",
                  "id":506
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dresses",
                  "id":507
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Jumpsuits",
                  "id":512
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Maternity",
                  "id":513
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Outerwear",
                  "id":514
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Shoes",
                  "id":515
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Sleepwear",
                  "id":528
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Socks & Hosiery",
                  "id":529
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Swimwear",
                  "id":539
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Tops & Tees",
                  "id":544
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Underwear",
                  "id":550
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Weatherwear & Accessories",
                  "id":568
               }
            ],
            "name":"Women",
            "id":439
         }
      ],
      "name":"Apparels , Accessories & Shoes",
      "id":247
   },
   {  
      "children":[  
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Services",
            "id":586
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Automobile",
                  "id":588
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Car Accessories",
                  "id":592
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Car Care",
                  "id":609
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Spare Parts",
                  "id":626
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Wheels & Tyres",
                  "id":641
               }
            ],
            "name":"Automotive",
            "id":587
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Air Refreshener",
                  "id":649
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Batteries",
                  "id":653
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dishwashing",
                  "id":654
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Household Cleaning",
                  "id":658
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Laundry",
                  "id":669
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Paper & Plastic",
                  "id":678
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Pest Control",
                  "id":684
               }
            ],
            "name":"Household essentials",
            "id":648
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Birds",
                  "id":695
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cats",
                  "id":704
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dogs",
                  "id":710
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fish & Aquatic Pets",
                  "id":717
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Small Animals",
                  "id":722
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pet feeding",
            "id":694
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Birds",
                  "id":730
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cats",
                  "id":731
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dogs",
                  "id":742
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fish & Aquatic Pets",
                  "id":753
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Small Animals",
                  "id":754
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pet Grooming",
            "id":729
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Birds",
                  "id":759
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cats",
                  "id":760
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dogs",
                  "id":761
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fish & Aquatic Pets",
                  "id":766
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Small Animals",
                  "id":769
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pet Housing",
            "id":758
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Birds",
                  "id":771
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cats",
                  "id":772
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dogs",
                  "id":778
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Small Animals",
                  "id":785
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pet Toys",
            "id":770
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Birds",
                  "id":787
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Cats",
                  "id":788
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Dogs",
                  "id":791
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fish & Aquatic Pets",
                  "id":794
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Small Animals",
                  "id":795
               }
            ],
            "name":"Pet travelling",
            "id":786
         }
      ],
      "name":"Automotive, Household & Pets",
      "id":585
   },
   {  
      "children":[  
         {  
            "children1":[  

            ],
            "name":"Services",
            "id":799
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Camera Accessories",
                  "id":801
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Compact Camera",
                  "id":810
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Digital Camera",
                  "id":811
               },
               {  
                  "name":"DSLR",
                  "id":812
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Interchangable Lens Camera",
                  "id":813
               }
            ],
            "name":"Cameras",
            "id":800
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"All-In-One",
                  "id":815
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Chromebooks",
                  "id":816
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Desktop",
                  "id":817
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Laptops Accessories",
                  "id":818
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Notebooks",
                  "id":822
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Ultrabooks",
                  "id":823
               }
            ],
            "name":"Computers",
            "id":814
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"All-In-One (AIO) Machines",
                  "id":825
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Computer Parts",
                  "id":826
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Fax Machine",
                  "id":831
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Keyboard",
                  "id":832
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Monitor",
                  "id":836
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Mouse",
                  "id":837
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Photocopying Machine",
                  "id":841
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Printer",
                  "id":842
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Scanner",
                  "id":845
               }
            ],
            "name":"Hardware",
            "id":824
         },
         {  
            "children1":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Audio",
                  "id":847
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Earpiece",
                  "id":855
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Headphone",
                  "id":859
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Home Entertainment Accessories",
                  "id":863
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Vision",
                  "id":868
               }
            ],
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your problem is here :

```
ng-click = "toggle123('{{ChildNames.id}}')">
```

that shall be

```
ng-click = "toggle123(ChildNames.id)">
```

Comment: I have done what you have said but it still not working. The {{ChildName.id}} is comming from json